# can we convert a live application to an InApp application in iphone?

Tags: iphone

**can we convert a live application to an In-App application in iPhone?**

I have an application which is already submitted in apple. Now I want to convert this application to InApp which previously was not. So what changes I have to make for doing this. Here I have used an apple id and also distribution id for developing this apps.

So for making it InApp, again I have to create id, or any other necessary things please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're asking if you can update an existing aplication that doesn't support In-App Purchases with a new version that does support In-App Purchases then yes.

You need to:

- create In-App Purchases for this application in iTunes Connect.

  (Manage Your Applications -> select app -> Manage In-App Purchases -> Create New)
- write a new version that supports In-App Purchases
- **thoroughly test** this new version: [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf)
- submit this tested new version

You have to handle this carefully. You'll have to offer your application (a new version) for free and enable only part of functionality.

When user makes an in-app purchase you enable complete functionality.

All the functionality should be coded in the same binary, part of it is just 'locked' until user makes a purchase.

**IMPORTANT**: If your app is currently available in App Store in full functionality you have to **make sure that your existing users won't have to buy an In-App purchase** - their app should be 'unlocked' at first launch. There are several ways to check if your app was allready installed or not. It's possible that you'll have to make additional intermediate update but that's completely another topic.

Comment: Can you help me for doing this: i just want to break my application into two portion in one portion everyone can download it and to see the result he/she have to buy the next portion of my app. Now the condition of my app is, if anyone wants to use it then first he/she have to buy it.

Comment: Where can i get coding help for doing this especially "Make sure that your existing users (if they allready bought your fully-functional app) won't have to buy it again" this condition must be fulfilled

Comment: can we view demo from apple after completing my apps?

Comment: I don't understant what you mean by demo. If you're asking if you can test how in-app purchases will work in your application then yes - it's possible. Process is well described in those two links i gave you. Make sure you study those documents well before testing - there's a special procedure for that.

Comment: Actually forst 2 days my apps is set free then it set to cost. I want to set free only those whose purchase it but not for the others who get it free. Is there any way to make restriction for my new coming In-App

Comment: If my application bundle identifier like that(companyname.com.productname). It will be any problem for converting it In-App. Actually when I am testing my In-App using sandbox and my app identifier like companyname.com.appname and product id like companyname.com.appname.inApp001. Every time in transaction "an error occurred". Is there any prolem in naming of my project or any other.

Comment: Yes I have log out from store and I have created this product id 4 days ago and also I have test account which i have created from iTunes test user account. I have another project which bundle identifier like com.companyname.appname and there In-App code is running ok but here in my current project its given my predefined error

Comment: ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments])
    {
        NSLog(@"Parental-control are disables");
        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"companyName.com.projectName.inApp01"]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];
     }

Comment: -(void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response{
    SKProduct *ValidProduct = nil;
    int count = [response.products count];
    if(count > 0)
        ValidProduct = [response.products objectAtIndex:0];
    else if(!ValidProduct)
        NSLog(@"No products are available!!!");
}  But it shows No products are available!!!

Comment: can we tell me why this "paymentWithProductIdentifier: is deprecated " worning?

Comment: it still works but it was deprecated in iOS 5.0 - you should use `+ (id)paymentWithProduct:(SKProduct *)product` instead

Comment: I have uploaded my InApp 10 days ago now my apps show ready for sale but when i am showing in Manage In-App purchases it still shows ready to submit. I have uploaded my apps using application loader. My apps works fine in testing label is there any extra procedure which i have not still fllowed. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Actually My InApp is nothing but only a view where is the result and description. I used my code as if([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]){
        SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"escaladesoft.com.abc.abc01"]];
        productsRequest.delegate = self;
        [productsRequest start];
    }. SO how can i submit it separately only this storyboard view.

Comment: You don't 'submit' it separately as a code. The only code you submit is the app. But you still have to enable the in-app-purchase in iTunes connect. First: you have to submit a screenshot of how your app looks like with in-app enabled

Comment: Sir may i talk to you in chat I am facing a lots of problem that's why i have to talk a lot. If you agree to talk to me in chat then please give me some information so that where i can do!!!!

Comment: Leave that metter, I have create InApp from iTunes and i tested it in my Imac on release and debug mode. It runs good. After that i have uploaded it using application loader. Now it is ready for sale but InApp portion is still ready to submit. So now what can i do

Comment: before my InApp upload it was just as paid app so for uploading this InApp i just upgrade my app version and upload my whole InApp code but it still showing waiting for review. After your submission of app is it any change in waiting for review portion or it was same as before. And also I am not understand that why in the detals of the app InApp section is not showing?

Comment: @Banshi: hello. You really should post a new question - this is completely new topic and others might give you much better suggestions on this than me. I never experimented much with orientation - all my apps are made for single orientation only. But you have to know that orientation is a read-only property (you can't set it).

Comment: I see happend automatically - possibly because of all the comments at your questions. I'll delete my comments here, also gave you some extra upvotes. Possibly you'll be able to post question tommorow (it takes some time for automatics to process) - you have to know that it's a bad practice to 'update' questions with lots of extra comments.

Comment: No problem. :) You should also delete your comments here. They're not much use for others.

Answer (score 0):

NO You can't do this way,App Store does not provide any Authentication about this, If You want to this in APP ,you have to launch again APP with inAPP Purchase Code,registration and other process.

Comment: So according to you i can not covert my previous app to In-App

Comment: for this you have to modify Code of APP and relaunch your APP like new Version

Comment: Can you help me for doing this: i just want to break my application into two portion in one portion everyone can download it and to see the result he/she have to buy the next portion of my app. Now the condition of my app is, if anyone wants to use it then first he/she have to buy it.